# How can I allow Github automerge to perform the merge without explicitly enabling it per pull request?

Tags: github, automation, pull-request

Is it possible to allow Githubs [auto-merge feature](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/automatically-merging-a-pull-request) to merge pull requests without requiring me to explicitly enable auto-merging on every pull request?

I have:

- Enabled `Allow auto-merge` in my repository settings
- Set branch protections with status checks
- Created a pull request where all requirements are met
- Pull request is not auto-merged

I am still required to manually select `Enable auto-merging` while the requirements/status checks are pending/running in order for the pull request to auto-merge.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. Instead, I would recommend using a GitHub action that would do the auto-merge for you, giving you the same behavior you were looking for.
Check out this GitHub action: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/merge-pull-requests-automerge-action

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it requires using GitHub Actions (or some other CI/automation tool).

There are some assumptions with this setup:

- The `main` branch is restricted who can push into it.
- Because `main` is restricted, create PAT (personal access token) "PAT_GITHUB_ACTIONS" for a user which has permission to push into the repository. The default GITHUB_TOKEN was not used.

  - Check https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/67124 for some more details about the tokens.

**Steps for enabling automatic automerge**

1. Create a file `./github/workflows/automerge.yml` in your repository with content below.

   - ```
     name: Enable Automerge
     on:
       pull_request:
         branches:
         - main
     jobs:
       Enable-Automerge:
         runs-on: ubuntu-latest
         steps:
           - name: Auto Merge
             run: gh pr merge --auto --merge "$PR_URL"
             env:
               PR_URL: ${{github.event.pull_request.html_url}}
               GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{secrets.PAT_GITHUB_ACTIONS}}
     ```
   - Replace [pull_request](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request) with [pull_request_target](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_target) if you also want to merge from private forks. Here's some discussion about the events https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26874.
2. Create a personal token for user which can push into the branch. Give permission `repo: Full control of private repositories`.
3. Add the token into repository -> Settings -> Secrets and variables -> Actions -> Repository secrets
4. Enable branch protection rules for `main` branch. For testing purposes simple rules were used.

   - Require a pull request before merging
   - Do not allow bypassing the above settings
   - Restrict who can push to matching branches

     - <the_user_with_personal_access_token>
5. Create a test pull request. It'll take couple seconds for the automation to kick in.